# Find minimum balance in mobile

Tags: algorithm

Alice have N relatives. She will talk to ith relative for exactly T[i] minutes. Each minute costs her 1 dollar . However, her relatives after the conversation, add a recharge of X[i] dollars in her mobile. Initially, she have M dollars balance in her mobile phone.

We need to find the minimum value of M, that she must have initially, in her phone, so that she don't run out of balance during any of the call (encounter negative balance).

**Note : Alice can call relatives in any order. Each relative will be called exactly once.**

Example : Let N=2 and pair T[i] X[i] for each of the two relative is as follow:

```
1 1
2 1
```

Then here answer is 2.

Now 1 ≤ N,X,T ≤ 10^5 . So what can be best way to find the minimum value of M. Brute solution won't work out so I want some O(N) or O(N*logN) approach

Comment: [Please read this post before you write any more code in future.](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/)

Comment: This looks like homework, so instead of a complete solution, here's a hint: Notice that if you take any two adjacent calls and swap their order, the total credit remaining at the end is unchanged, but the lowest amount of credit after the first call could change -- so one of these orders will always be better.  How to decide which?

Comment: @j_random_hacker u can change the order of input .. U cannot swap ..

Answer (score 0):

We maintain the difference between call cost
  and recharge amount.

Then we maintain two arrays/vectors.
  If our recharge amount is strictly greater than cost of call, we put
  the call in the first array ,else we put it in the second array.

Then we can sort the first array according to the cost and the second array
  according to the recharge amount. We then update the diff by adding the
  least amount of recharge from the call where our cost is greater than recharge

Then we can iterate through our first array and update our max
  requirement,requirement for each call and current balance.Finally, our answer
  will be the maximum between max requirement and the diff we have maintained.

**Example :-**

```
   N = 2
   T1 = 1 R1 = 1
   T2 = 2 R2 = 1
```

Our first array contains nothing as all the calls have cost greater than 
   or equal to recharge amount. So, we place both calls in our second array
   The diff gets updated to 2 before we sort the array. Then, we add the min
   recharge we can get from the calls to our diff(i.e 1).Now, the diff stands
   at 3.Then as our first array contains no elements, our answer is equal to
   the diff i.e 3.

**Time Complexity :- O(n)**

**Working Example:-**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define MAXN 100007

int n,diff;
vector<pair<int,int> > v1,v2;

int main(){
    diff = 0;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    int cost,recharge;
    cin>>cost>>recharge;
    if(recharge > cost){
       v1.push_back(make_pair(cost,recharge));
    }else{
       v2.push_back(make_pair(recharge,cost));
    }
    diff += (cost-recharge);
   }
   sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
   sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
   if(v2.size() > 0)diff += v2[0].first;
   int max_req = diff, req = 0,cur = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<v1.size(); i++){
      req = v1[i].first - cur;
      max_req = max(max_req, req);
      cur += v1[i].second-v1[i].first;
   }
   cout<<max(max_req,diff)<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```