# How to find the minimum value of M?

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> You have N relatives. You will talk to ith relative for exactly Ti
>   minutes. Each minute costs you 1 dollar .  After the conversation,
>   they will add a recharge of Xi dollars in your mobile. Initially, you
>   have M dollars balance in your mobile phone.
>
> Find the minimum value of M, that you must have initially, in your
>   phone, so that you don't run out of balance during any of the call
>   (encounter negative balance).
>
> Note : You can call relatives in any order. Each relative will be
>   called exactly once.

**Input:**

```
N
T1  X1
T2  X2

2
1 1 
2 1
```

**Output:**

```
2
```

This looks easy to me at first but I'm not able to find the exact solution.

**My Initial thoughts:**

> We have no problem where `Xi > Ti` as it will not reduce our initial
>   balance. We need to take care of situation where where we will run
>   into loss i.e `Ti > Xi`. 
>   But I am unable to make expression which will result in minimum
>   initial value.

Need guidance in approaching this problem to find optimal solution.

Comment: please provide the reason for the downvote.Don't downvote without providing any reasons for downvote.

Comment: Did not downvote, but questions should be self contained.You need to provide the question in the thread itself, and not only via a link. In addition, you did not show what you have tried.

Comment: And, the link is unavailable without registering, so most of readers cannot see the question anyway.

Comment: Ok..I'll edit it... I thought the question will be available. thanks.

Comment: Re-think the very first thought: What if you start with one dollar andt talk far 2 minutes to one refunding 3? (I doubt there _is_ a closed expression.)

Comment: @greybeard yes you are right. I understood that part after few example. But I an unable to think of any way to get the solution.

Comment: @Cyclotron3x3 looks like a variation of knapsack to me, am I right?

Comment: You started by trying to categorise (T, X) pairs/relatives: that approach holds promise. Two categories are Ti<Xi and Ti>Xi - are there more? What can be stated about the funds neccessary for a call to one of each? Can you devise an advantageous order of calls? (Counting our typos, none of us should post in a haste.)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:-**

Binary Search approach seems to lead to wrong result (as proved by the 
  test case provided in the comment below by user [greybeard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3789665/greybeard).

So, this is another approach.We maintain the difference between call cost
  and recharge amount.

Then we maintain two arrays/vectors.
  If our recharge amount is strictly greater than cost of call, we put
  the call in the first array ,else we put it in the second array.

Then we can sort the first array according to the cost and the second array
  according to the recharge amount. We then update the diff by adding the
  least amount of recharge from the call where our cost is greater than recharge

Then we can iterate through our first array and update our max
  requirement,requirement for each call and current balance.Finally, our answer
  will be the maximum between max requirement and the diff we have maintained.

**Example :-**

```
   N = 2
   T1 = 1 R1 = 1
   T2 = 2 R2 = 1
```

Our first array contains nothing as all the calls have cost greater than 
   or equal to recharge amount. So, we place both calls in our second array
   The diff gets updated to 2 before we sort the array. Then, we add the min
   recharge we can get from the calls to our diff(i.e 1).Now, the diff stands
   at 3.Then as our first array contains no elements, our answer is equal to
   the diff i.e 3.

**Time Complexity :- O(nlogn)**

**Working Example:-**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define MAXN 100007

int n,diff;
vector<pair<int,int> > v1,v2;

int main(){
    diff = 0;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    int cost,recharge;
    cin>>cost>>recharge;
    if(recharge > cost){
       v1.push_back(make_pair(cost,recharge));
    }else{
       v2.push_back(make_pair(recharge,cost));
    }
    diff += (cost-recharge);
   }
   sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
   sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
   if(v2.size() > 0)diff += v2[0].first;
   int max_req = diff, req = 0,cur = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<v1.size(); i++){
      req = v1[i].first - cur;
      max_req = max(max_req, req);
      cur += v1[i].second-v1[i].first;
   }
   cout<<max(max_req,diff)<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your solution looks promising. But isn't that O(nlogn) solution. How to check whether it never reaches 0 while there are still calls left ? Linearly?? It would we good if you can demonstrate your algorithm with an small example. Thanks

Comment: @user2125722  thanks. U added the code too :)  but I asked for demonstration. with an example. any small example to show how your code works.Thanks.. you helped so far, just one last update..

Comment: I see a costly, if valid way of finding the minimum starting funds for calls in the order the (T, X)-pairs are specified. The Problem explicitly states: `Note : You can call relatives in any order.` - is there a "cheaper" order?

Comment: @greybeard Changed the algorithm as your test case failed my previous approach.

Comment: Now the approach looks valid, but the run time analysis deserves elaboration: how is sort {T<X} O(n)? Is it necessary to sort the rest? (be out for ~8 hours)

Comment: @greybeard Sorry,it will be O(nlogn) in worst case.

Comment: @user2125722  Add an example which shows all your mentioned steps.Current example does not provide full insight. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Working efficiently means accomplishing the task at hand, with no undue effort. Aspects here:

- the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3646917/cyclotron3x3) asks for `guidance in approaching this problem to find optimal solution` - *not* for a solution (as this [entirely similar, older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30149449/3789665) does).
- the problem statement asks for `the minimum value of M` - *not* an optimal order of calls or how to find that.

To find the minimum balance initially required, categorise the relatives/(T, X)-pairs/calls (the order *might* have a meaning, if not for the problem as stated)

1. T < X Leaves X-T more for calls to follow. Do in order of increasing cost.
   Start assuming an initial balance of 1. For each call, if you can afford it, subtract its cost, add its refund and be done accounting for it. If you can't afford it (yet), put it on hold/the back burner/in a priority queue. At the end of "rewarding calls", remove each head of the queue in turn, accounting for necassary increases in intitial balance.
   This part ends with a *highest balance, yet*.
2. T = X No influence on any other call. Just do at top balance, in any order.
   The top balance required for the whole sequence can't be lower than the cost of any single call, including these.
3. T > X Leaves T-X less for subsequent calls. Do in order of decreasing refund.
   (This may, as any call, go to a balance of zero before refund.
   As order of calls does not change the total cost, the ones requiring the least initial balance will be those yielding the lowest final one. For the intermediate balance required by this category, don't forget that least refund.)

Combine the requirements from all categories.

Comment: Didn't get this line, "the ones requiring the least initial balance will be those yielding the lowest final one. ". Can you add a demonstration with an example .  Since its a wiki it will be more beneficial.

Comment: If I knew what kind of demonstration you have in mind, I might be able to. (code in [Beta](http://cs.au.dk/~beta/)?). This being a wiki post, please try adding how to _construct_ a set of pairs with `T<X` that _cannot_ be enlisted in an order requiring the least initial funds without sorting. Argue whether or not sorting _is_ neccessary to name `M` (may yield a lower bound). Continue with an argument about `T>X` to see if you can find a correction for the condition you haven't got yet (it _might_ be wrong &hellip;), or a more appealing or intuitive formulation - you've got the reputation.

Comment: what I meant was an example. .:)